# Stop window from getting focus on click on it

Tags: visual-c++, wxwidgets, pjsip

Hello I am using pjsua http://www.pjsip.org/pjsua.htm and I am making video call application. My problem is that when I establish a connection and video is on, if I click on the video, the video window gets the focus. So in that moment I can not use the keyboard shortcuts for my application (because now the video window is on focus). I need to stop the video window from being clickable at all so that it never gets focus.

Comment: The window gets the WM_MOUSEACTIVATE message to tell that it was clicked.  It should return MA_NOACTIVATEANDEAT if it shouldn't be activated.  Shortcut keystrokes should always be handled by the message loop so it doesn't matter which window has the focus.  TranslateAccelerator is the boilerplate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem just by editing the mouse event SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN of the SDL Window. I've used [BringWindowToTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it does the job to return the focus to the window that I want to.

Answer (score 0):

If your video window is implemented in wxWidgets, you can handle `wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN` event and *not* skip it, i.e. avoid calling `event.Skip()` in your handler. This will prevent the default handler from executing and giving the focus to the window. However it won't prevent the user from doing it in some other way, e.g. by using `Alt-TAB`.

So a better idea would be to just ensure that you handle the keyboard events in the video window too.

Comment: No, the video is pjmedia, that is also part of pjsip. Anyway I fixed the problem other way